# Shape mismatch when implementing Info NCE loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, self-supervised-learning

I'm trying to implement the Info NCE loss of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03748.pdf) with my own image dataset. I'm following the implementation from this [repo](https://github.com/sthalles/SimCLR/tree/master) and using the following code:

```
def info_nce_loss(self, features):

        labels = torch.cat([torch.arange(self.args.batch_size) for i in range(self.args.n_views)], dim=0)
        labels = (labels.unsqueeze(0) == labels.unsqueeze(1)).float()
        labels = labels.to(self.args.device)

        features = F.normalize(features, dim=1)

        similarity_matrix = torch.matmul(features, features.T)
        # assert similarity_matrix.shape == (
        #     self.args.n_views * self.args.batch_size, self.args.n_views * self.args.batch_size)
        # assert similarity_matrix.shape == labels.shape

        # discard the main diagonal from both: labels and similarities matrix
        mask = torch.eye(labels.shape[0], dtype=torch.bool).to(self.args.device)
        labels = labels[~mask].view(labels.shape[0], -1)
        similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix[~mask].view(similarity_matrix.shape[0], -1)
        # assert similarity_matrix.shape == labels.shape

        # select and combine multiple positives
        positives = similarity_matrix[labels.bool()].view(labels.shape[0], -1)

        # select only the negatives the negatives
        negatives = similarity_matrix[~labels.bool()].view(similarity_matrix.shape[0], -1)

        logits = torch.cat([positives, negatives], dim=1)
        labels = torch.zeros(logits.shape[0], dtype=torch.long).to(self.args.device)

        logits = logits / self.args.temperature
        return logits, labels
```

to train my model in a self-supervised manner. I was using `batch_size` of 32 with the above loss function in my code and everything was working fine. But when I change the `batch_size` to any other number for instance, 256, I get the following error:

```
The shape of the mask [512, 512] at index 0 does not match the shape of the indexed tensor [2, 2] at index 0.
```

The error originates at this line:

```
labels = labels[~mask].view(labels.shape[0], -1)
```

I tried resizing my images but that didn't help either. Any idea on what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It was previously reported [here](https://github.com/sthalles/SimCLR/issues/40) and recently [here](https://github.com/sthalles/SimCLR/issues/60). However, the code was still not updated. It seems this line:

```
labels = torch.cat([torch.arange(self.args.batch_size) for i in range(self.args.n_views)], dim=0)
```

is dependant on `batch_size` and was causing the issue. The above line needs to be replaced with either: `labels = torch.cat([torch.arange(features.shape[0]//2) for i in range(self.args.n_views)], dim=0)`

OR: `labels = torch.cat([torch.arange(features.shape[0]//self.args.n_views) for i in range(self.args.n_views)], dim=0)`

Based on that change, the correct loss function would be:

```
def info_nce_loss(self, features):

        labels = torch.cat([torch.arange(features.shape[0]//2) for i in range(self.args.n_views)], dim=0)
        labels = (labels.unsqueeze(0) == labels.unsqueeze(1)).float()
        labels = labels.to(self.args.device)

        features = F.normalize(features, dim=1)

        similarity_matrix = torch.matmul(features, features.T)
        # assert similarity_matrix.shape == (
        #     self.args.n_views * self.args.batch_size, self.args.n_views * self.args.batch_size)
        # assert similarity_matrix.shape == labels.shape

        # discard the main diagonal from both: labels and similarities matrix
        mask = torch.eye(labels.shape[0], dtype=torch.bool).to(self.args.device)
        labels = labels[~mask].view(labels.shape[0], -1)
        similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix[~mask].view(similarity_matrix.shape[0], -1)
        # assert similarity_matrix.shape == labels.shape

        # select and combine multiple positives
        positives = similarity_matrix[labels.bool()].view(labels.shape[0], -1)

        # select only the negatives the negatives
        negatives = similarity_matrix[~labels.bool()].view(similarity_matrix.shape[0], -1)

        logits = torch.cat([positives, negatives], dim=1)
        labels = torch.zeros(logits.shape[0], dtype=torch.long).to(self.args.device)

        logits = logits / self.args.temperature
        return logits, labels
```